# Babel 7 & SystemJS 2: "Unable to resolve bare specifier core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable"

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, systemjs

I use Babel 7 with the polyfill and the systemjs plugins, which causes the following error:

`Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Unable to resolve bare specifier "core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable" from file:///[...]/target/main.js"`

How can I tell Babel to produce transpiled code that can be run in SystemJS without errors?

The transpiled code looks like this:

```
"use strict";

System.register(["core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable", "core-js/modules/es6.set", "./loadGraphFromSparql.js", "./log.js", "./filter.js", "./menu.js", "./search.js", "./button.js", "./graph.js", "./file.js", "./rdfGraph.js", "./layout.js", "./progress.js"], function (_export, _context) {
  "use strict";
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "cytoscape": "^3.2.17",
    "cytoscape-cxtmenu": "^3.0.1",
    "cytoscape-euler": "^1.2.1",
    "spin.js": "^4.0.0",
    "systemjs": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "docdash": "^1.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "eslint": "^5.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.5",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "node-localstorage": "^1.3.1"
  },
  [...]
  "scripts":
  {
    "build": "babel js -d target", [...]
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets":
  [[
    "@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 52,
        "browsers": ["Firefox 49", "Edge 12","Chrome 53", "Opera 41", "Safari 10"]
      },
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }]],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs"]
}
```

Edit:
As suggested by @loganfsmyth, I removed the dependency to @babel-polyfill. I also added a systemjs-packagemap to include the bare imports. Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: Error loading file:///.../myproject/node_modules/core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable from file:///.../myproject/target/main.js
Stack trace:
h.instantiate/</<@file:///.../myproject/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js:4:4817
core.min.js
```

It seems as if system.js forgets to add the .js at the end of the file, because web.dom.iterable exists.

The relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="systemjs-packagemap">
    {
    "packages": {
        "core-js":
            {
                "path": "./node_modules/core-js/",
                "main": "client/core.min.js"
            }
    }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/s.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    System.import("./target/main.js");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I was unable to fix this problem and moved to Webpack with Babel without SystemJS. However I am still be interested in a solution.

Answer (score 2):

@babel/polyfill has been deprecated, so instead use following two,

```
npm i --save core-js regenerator-runtime
```

then remove `import "@babel/polyfill";`

and add these two

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

as described here

https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md

Answer (score 1):

See Babel's docs for `preset-env`'s `useBuiltins` option: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins

> This option adds direct references to the core-js module as bare imports. Thus core-js will be resolved relative to the file itself and needs to be accessible. You may need to specify core-js@2 as a top level dependency in your application if there isn't a core-js dependency or there are multiple versions.

so you need a dependency on `"core-js": "^2.5.7"` in your `package.json` and then you need to make sure that code is bundled into your application.

Comment: I thought core-js is already included through @babel/polyfill. According to https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill: "Babel includes a polyfill that includes a custom regenerator runtime and core-js."

Comment: If you're using `@babel/polyfill`, then you don't want `"useBuiltIns": "usage"`. They are two different approaches to polyfilling, so you'd want to use one or the order.

Comment: I am going to put your code with the change in GitHub in case it works. Or if someone can fix it.